# How to style Group Headers of RadDataForm?

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue, nativescript-telerik-ui

[DataForm docs](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/components/DataForm/dataform-styling#styling-group-headers) says; I  need to create an instance of *GroupTitleStyle* and set it to the *PropertyGroup*'s *titleStyle* property.

### But how and where to create `grouptitlestyle`  in nativescript-vue?

I have created an [{N} playground](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=rqK7wO&v=8)

I already tried:

```js
         return {
             groups: [
                    Object.assign(new PropertyGroup(), {
                        name: "Personal",
                        collapsible: true,
                        collapsed: false,
                        titleStyle: {
                            labelTextSize: 22
                        }
                    }),

                    Object.assign(new PropertyGroup(), {
                        name: "Address",
                        collapsible: true,
                        collapsed: true
                    })
                ],
```

Would you please help me to **set** `labelTextSize` to RadDataForm **groups**?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply pass `GroupTitleStyle` instance, not plain object.

```
      ....
               Object.assign(new PropertyGroup(), {
                    name: "Personal",
                    collapsible: true,
                    collapsed: false,
                    titleStyle: Object.assign(
                    new GroupTitleStyle(), {
                        labelTextSize: 40
                    })
                }),
     ....
```

[Updated Playground](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=rqK7wO&v=9)